# not able to use session attribute value inside exec http method in gatling

Tags: scala-gatling

```
    I am trying to pass the session ArrayBuffer element to exec http method directly . However this exec http is getting called at all.
    
    Session output is below :
    Session(6UsersAtOnce,6,1606715840791,Map(gatling.http.cache.baseUrl -> https://dbp-services-gateway-dk0859-a.uki1f.paas.intranet.db.com/pace-cake-servic
    e, email -> type5.dbpalace@db.com, gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.cache.DnsCacheSupport$$anon$1@1c2c0d4d, sliceSubGrps -> ArrayBuffer(57,59,
    1,62, 63,2, 3,24, 61,0), id -> type5-dbpalace-6, gatling.http.ssl.sslContexts -> SslContexts(io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext@7
    71aed4f,None), slices -> [57,59,1,62,63,2,3,24,61,0]),28,OK,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$562/0x00000008005fe840@2e
    84544c)
    
    Here is the code that I am using.
```

rest call to fetch slice information. "slices" is the response and sample value is [57,59,1,62,63,2,3,24,61,0] which is saved in session

```
    def metadata() = http("metadata")
                    .get("/data/metadata/" + cob + "?filter_name=Full%20Entitlements&request_id=${id}")
                    .check(status.is(200))
                    .check(jsonPath("$.slices")
                          .saveAs("**slices**"))
```

rest call to chunk to fetch table data
input to this rest call is **slices** fetched from above metadata REST call.

```
      def chunk(chunk: Int, slices: String) = http("chunk_" + chunk)
                          .get("/data/chunk/csv/" + cob + "?slices=" + slices + "&request_id=${id}")
                          .check(status.is(200))
```

ChainBuilder which will build the chain of command.

```
      val loadOnce: ChainBuilder = feed(userFeeder)
        .exec(session =>
          session.set("id", session.attributes("email").toString
                            .replace("@db.com", "-")
                            .replace(".", "-")
                            + session.userId.toString)
        )
        .exec(metadata())
        .pause(100.milliseconds)
        .exec(session => {
          val sliceList = session("slices").as[String]
            .replace("[", "")
            .replace("]", "")
            .split(",")
          val noofSlicesPerChunkRequests = (sliceList.length+TOTAL_REQUESTS-1)/TOTAL_REQUESTS
          var sliceSubGrp = ""
          
          var varSliceSubGrps = ArrayBuffer[String]()
          var i=0
          var j=0
          for (slice <- sliceList) {
            sliceSubGrp = sliceSubGrp + slice
            i+=1
            j+=1
            if(i < noofSlicesPerChunkRequests && j<sliceList.length){
              sliceSubGrp = sliceSubGrp + ","
            }else{
              varSliceSubGrps += sliceSubGrp
              sliceSubGrp=""
              i=0
            }
          }
          val sliceSubGrps = varSliceSubGrps
          session.set("sliceSubGrps", sliceSubGrps)
        }).exec(session => {
        val sliceArray = session("sliceSubGrps").as[ArrayBuffer[String]]
        println(sliceArray)
        println(s"Element at index 0 = ${sliceArray(0)}")
        session
        }).exec(chunk(1, s"${session("sliceSubGrps").as[ArrayBuffer[String]](0)}"))
        .pause(100.milliseconds)
```

How to pass sliceSubGrps elements one by one to exec(chunk()) method?
the java version would look like below
for(int i=0;i<sliceSubGrps.size();i++)
{
exec(chunk(1,sliceSubGrps(i)))
}
how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your last block is wrong:

```scala
exec(chunk(1, s"${session("sliceSubGrps").as[ArrayBuffer[String]](0)}"))
```

The `s""` is [Scala String interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html), not Gatling Expression Language. It won't compile because there's no `session` reference in scope.

Please properly read the [Gatling EL documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/).

You have to redesign your chunk method so that you pass Gatling expressions to the Gatling DSL methods, eg:

```
.get("/data/chunk/csv/" + cob + "?slices=${sliceSubGrps(0)}&request_id=${id}")
```